# Angular table header color and display

Tags: css, angular, mat-table

I'm trying to change the color for place holder in Angular mat table header to white, but all it is not working.

And also, I want to show the full text "Action" instead of "A..." 
How to solve this one?

[image]

HTML code :

```
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> 

        <mat-select placeholder="Action" (selectionChange)="filter($event)">
           <mat-option value="all"> View All </mat-option>
           <mat-option value="some"> View some</mat-option>
         </mat-select>
    </th>
```

CSS :

```
th {
  color: white;
}

.mat-select-value-text {
  color: white !important;
}
.mat-select-panel mat-option.mat-option {
  height: unset;
  color: white;
}

.mat-option-text.mat-option-text {
  white-space: normal;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in your css

```
:host /deep/ .mat-select-value-text { }
```

I’ve also tried but doesn’t work

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-value-text { }
```

Maybe this can help you

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/